# Traktor copied my music collection to the Documents folder which is taking up space in iCloud - what happens if I delete it?

Tags: mac, traktor

On a Mac, I installed Traktor 3, in order to play a curated collection of dance music from a folder in Google Drive (`~/gdrive/choons`), but at some point, my entire music collection, from `~/Music` got copied into the Traktor root directory: `~/Documents/Native Instruments/Traktor 3.1.1`. So for instance, in `~/Music`, there are folders for different collections of music, e.g. `000albums`, `000mixes`, etc (I prefix them with `000` so they appear at the top of listings in the Finder and in the terminal). These have been copied at some point - not by me - to `~/Documents/Native Instruments/Traktor 3.1.1`. There is over 120Gb of files in `~/Music`, and almost all of it has been copied to the Traktor root dir, which is well over the 5Gb free storage in iCloud and causes frequent warnings that my iCloud storage is full - not to mention taking up an extra 120Gb of space on my hard drive. I don't want them in iCloud at all, I don't want unnecessary copies, and in fact, this is not the collection of tracks I want in Traktor anyway - those are in `~/gdrive/choons`, which is added as an extra music folder in Traktor.

So I am tempted to delete the music in `~/Documents/Native Instruments/Traktor 3.1.1` - but what might happen? Why are they there in the first place? Obviously I don't want to lose my music collection in `~/Music`, and I don't want Traktor to start copying them again.

Comment: This seems like a basic NI Traktor support question. Is Native Instruments customer service not answering you?